# Cryptogram: $XYZ\div8 = ZX$, remainder $Y$

Tags: problem-solving, puzzle

Say we have the division algorithm

[image]

Where X,Y,Z represent a non-zero digit and the remainder is Y. What is the three-digit number XYZ?

From what I gather, I re-arranged the division into an equation: 
$$100x+10y+z = 8x+y+80z$$

Which simplifies into 
$$92x+9y = 79z$$
This equation is unhelpful, since it contains three variables. What other equations can I derive to find the value of each pro numeral? Should I consider long division properties to find more expressions?

Comment: You have yet to use the fact that $x,y,z\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Comment: You are missing the fact that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ have to be integers! Clue: the solution is $X=4$, $Y=3$, and $Z=5$.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo How is that a clue?

Comment: It's a clue in the sense that there is a solution; now it's just a matter of finding it and proving that it is the only one.

Comment: Well finding it is now no longer an issue, I guess.

Comment: you could express xyz as 100x+10y+z, and use the fact that the remainder is less than 8, and you could then apply integer programming to get x,y and z given that they are bounded by 1 and 9.

Comment: @RiccardoSvenRisuleo What was your process of finding the values, did you utilize modular arithmetic or did you use another method?

Comment: To be honest, three nested for loops :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't yet used the fact that $x,y,z\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, which greatly restricts the possibilities.

For example, reducing the equation you found modulo $79$ shows that
$$13x+9y\equiv0\pmod{79},$$
where $13\times(-6)\equiv1\pmod{79}$, so this shows that $54y\equiv x\pmod{79}$. Then there are *very* few options left for $x$ and $y$...